# How to be visible in google cast ios app?

Tags: google-cast

I've included Google Cask SDK v3 in an ios app and it works nicely.
But i can't find any doc on how to include the app in the Google cast ios app, in order to improve its discovery and adoption.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is only supported for the Cast partner apps. Your app will be listed on chromecast.com/apps and in the Android Google Cast app if the user has installed the Android version of your app.

Comment: Ok that's a good answer. Any person to contact for partnership, or link ?

Comment: Could you please help me with these ? 1) 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474728/viewing-pdf-files-in-chromecast.  2) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178424585 3) https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios/issues/98